# Simple foreign key join to check if any value is there

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm just trying to see if a particular user has a single resulting row of an inner join between these two tables:

```
create table course
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table persons
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  username varchar(255),
  courseid int,
  foreign key (courseid) references course(id)
)
```

Basically my query goes:

"If user `SERGIO` is in any course that starts with the letter `SVU`?" If there is any resulting row, I'd like to return true in my PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will simply return a single row with a column called `found` if a course starting with `SVU` via the [`LEFT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)  is found for `SERGIO`. The `DISTINCT` serves to deduplicate multiple rows if the user matches multiple courses beginning with `SVU`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS found
FROM
  persons 
  JOIN course ON persons.courseid = course.id
WHERE 
  LEFT(course.name, 3) = 'SVU'
  AND username = 'SERGIO'
```

#### [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4dba/1)

I assume you already know how to query this in PHP and fetch the result with whatever MySQL API you are using (MySQLi, PDO, or the old `mysql_*()`)